# tableFooterView xib with autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, tablefooterview

I finally managed to clean enough screen to activate the autolayout on a legacy project. Woohoo!

I have a `UITableView` that has a xib (only a xib - has no h/m files) as a `tableFooterView`.
I added some constraints (the problem I'm about to described happened before and after the constraints - they didn't change anything).
Snippet form the xib editor:
[image]

The code is:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"addCommentView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
commentTextField = (UITextField *)[self.tableView.tableFooterView viewWithTag:1];
commentTextField.delegate = self;

UIButton *sendButton = (UIButton *)[self.tableView.tableFooterView viewWithTag:2];
[sendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSendComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What I'm seeing is this - No grey background of the view and the textField is not editable.
[image]
It worked before autolayouting the storyboard itself...

Would appreciate some ideas where to look for the problem...

Comment: I tried to duplicate your problem, but couldn't. Creating the view in a xib with what I think are the same constraints as yours worked fine. Do you have any other constraints on the text field or button?

Comment: Well, I wound up making it a `UITableViewCell` and add it as another section instead of a footer. The visuality is the same and it behaves better (cellHeight etc.)